# Listing files on wear os 4 (android 13)

Tags: file-permissions, wear-os

I'm really having a hard time on this; I need to list all files/folders from the watch internal storage...

On wear os 3, I simply use a .listFiles() from io.File and thats it. On wear os 4 it doesnt list any files...

To "solve" the problem I added/request the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

which seems that has replaced the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on wear 4... however, this only list (as it says), images, audios and videos, it does not list other kinds of files like txt, pdf apk and so on, nor allow me to "manage" those files (edit/delete and so on)... my question is **how do I do to list all kinds of files?**

I'm really confused, because, if I'm not wrong wear os 4 is based on android 13, and on android 13 I can list/edit/delete/... all files using:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```